# Synthetic VoIP using Java

Tags: java, voip

How might I generate [synthetic VoIP](http://www.xo.com/SiteCollectionDocuments/business-services/data-and-internet-services/mpls-ip-vpn-service/Whitepaper_VoIP_Assessment.pdf) calls, for testing, using Java?

Are there any open source packages that handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a lot of SIP implementations in Java

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Open+Source+VOIP+Software

Answer (score 0):

The Festival Speech Synthesis system is really cool: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Festival_Speech_Synthesis_System

It itself is native code, but it's available for all the major platforms and there are Java access wrappers there as well.
Very sophisticated and sounds excellent IMO.